# How do I strong name a C++ assembly in VS2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, strongname

I have no experience developing C++ on Windows, but I am a C# developer.

I have a wrapper around some native DLLs that is written in C++.  (A LGPL project)).  I was to use this from a strong named assembly.

How do I set up the strong naming of the C++ assembly?  There is no 'Signing' properties tab available as there is in C# projects.

I imagine that I need to edit the vcproj file and put a reference to the key file, something like

```
 /KEYFILE:"sgKey.snk"
```

that I found at this site: http://www.windows-tech.info/17/6a8f0ab94246fb61.php

I'm sure it will be easy once I find the right reference.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

An easy question for C++ devs to get some rep points out of.

Thanks.

Comment: I think I've found it.  Why does sometimes the property page fail to load...

Comment: Is this a C++/CLI project? AFAIK StrongName signing has no meaning (and in fact is impossible) for native assemblies...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it.  For some reason the first time I clicked on the project the property pages came up empty.  On retry I found it in the project property page.

```
Configuration Propertyes|Linker|Advanced|Key File.
```

And just enter the path to the snk key file.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: This is a bug that's gotten me a few times in Visual Studio. Sometimes when you go to project properties, you have to select the project again once the property window is open or it displays empty.