# Signing assemblies with strong name and certificate

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly-signing, strong-named-key

I understand that for strongly named C++ dll's I need to:

1. [create a Strong-Name Key File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788548.aspx).
2. Assign the Strong Name to the project, by [add the key properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblykeyfileattribute(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-3), (this way required to [Set Common Language RunTime Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732789/system-a-namespace-with-this-name-does-not-exist/20595744#20595744)), or to [specify the key file we will use at: Project-> Properties-> Configuration Properties-> Linker-> Advanced-> Key File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389886/how-do-i-strong-name-a-c-assembly-in-vs2008?answertab=votes#tab-top) (this way didn't work to me).

3.Sign the .dll by the [SN tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23(v=vs.110).aspx): `sn.exe -R dll_file.dll key_file.snk`

Since step 2 required Visual C++ project change (CLR support or specify file key), I'm wondering if there is a way to sign without changing the existing project, because I don't want to touch something that works...

Any idea?

Comment: Step 2 was what I needed, so thank you, hope you found a solution that worked